# How to know somebody's IP? (Fraud victim)

Tags: ip-spoofing, fraud

I was victim of fraud (fool me) in Mexico and my only hint is a GMail account, so I can contact him from an anonymous mail.

From what I've read, GMail's headers don't contain the sender's IP. What are my options to get the sender's IP? Some link that he can click and log his IP? I just want at least a hint on where he is.

Comment: Why do you think the email address is still live?

Comment: Can you get help from authorities? I'd recommend trying that before going on a hunt of your own? Especially being the criminal can likely find you.

Comment: @NeilSmithline I sent an email to the fraud post and got a reply, and I don't really trust authorities, but I will give it a shot too

Comment: _Criminal can likely find you._ Given what goes on in Mexico, the better answer here is to cut your line, let the shark get away, cut your losses and stay alive.

Comment: I assume that you are a relatively law abiding person. We know that the party you are tracking is a criminal. At least for me, this raises concerns about the safety of you being tracked by the attacker.

Answer (score 4):

If you can trick them into clicking something in an email, you can send them a link to any page that you have access to the webserver logs for and find the request in the log (along with their IP).  There are also a number of third party services to do this for you that are pretty easy to use (eg http://whatstheirip.com).

Now, that said, some of the scammers out there are highly dangerous individuals with organised crime connections.  Think twice before tangling with these people and consider the value of the money you've lost vs the potential cost to you and your family if they decide to try and hurt you.  These people may be quite comfortable resorting to murder or kidnap to get their way, do you really want to move out from behind a computer screen and face someone like this in person?

Comment: also notably if the attacker was connected to through vpn/proxy the link will fetch only spoofed ip,